# CSS grid as child of flexbox not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have often created a responsive 3-column grid with CSS `display: grid`.  My HTML markup inside the grid has 3 `div` items, so the grid creates 3 columns

```css
display: grid;
grid-gap: 2rem;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
```

[image]

and as you resize the window it collapses to 1 column, as expected:

https://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/oqMjrd?editors=1100

```css
.hero-modules {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

.hero-modules .hero-item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-modules .hero-item h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-modules">
  <div class="hero-item">
    <div>
      <h3>Title of Item</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="hero-read-more">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hero-item">
    <div>
      <h3>Title of Item</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="hero-read-more">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hero-item">
    <div>
      <h3>Title of Item</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="hero-read-more">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I need to use this grid inside a Flexbox, to center the enclosing box to float on the link background:

[image]

And as you can see, the grid collapses (the dotted border is only added to show the extents of the flex child).

https://codepen.io/smlombardi/pen/PRBPWB?editors=1100

```css
.hero {
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 600px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-unit {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.hero-modules {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

.hero-modules .hero-item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-modules .hero-item h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1 class="hero-heading">Check out these new features</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="hero-modules">
      <div class="hero-item">
        <div>
          <h3>Title of Item</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a class="hero-read-more">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="hero-item">
        <div>
          <h3>Title of Item</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a class="hero-read-more">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="hero-item">
        <div>
          <h3>Title of Item</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a class="hero-read-more">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button-unit">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary mb-3">Got It</button>
      <p>
        <a class="remind-me-later" href="">Remind me later</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum molestias earum beatae, minima provident sunt a et? Voluptatibus sequi ipsum ad asperiores soluta odio, nam nobis quas non totam ut officiis itaque eveniet, maiores saepe id cum consequuntur.
      Molestias suscipit quia laudantium laborum nemo ab officia, nihil esse mollitia sunt!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is this happening?  Is there something I am missing not allowing the grid to behave normally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Simple Answer:**

The grid container's automatic width is essentially whatever it would be if it weren't a grid container.

In the first example, the grid container width is only constrained by the width of the document and any default margins.

In the second example, the grid container width is the width of an ancestor flex item with default shrinkwrap behavior that's dependent on the width of its content, the text "*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.*" (To put it more directly, the width of the grid container is the width of the preceding, quoted sentence.)

**The Extended Answer:**

The grid container (`.hero-modules`) has `width: auto` (the default). Per https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#grid-container:

> As a block-level box in a block formatting context, it is sized like a block box that establishes a formatting context, with an auto inline size calculated as for non-replaced block boxes.

The term "auto inline size" is just another way of saying `width: auto` in this case. (The "auto inline size" is `height: auto` in vertical text.)

"A block box that establishes a formatting context" is the same as a box with `display: flow-root`. Changing `display: grid` to `display: flow-root` will demonstrate what width is being used to calculate the width of the grid container as a result of `width: auto`.

So now we know where the grid container size comes from.

The flex item's size comes from `flex-grow: 0` and `flex-shrink: 1` (the defaults), which makes its width shrink and not grow. The basis for the flex item's width is `flex-basis: auto` (the default), which resolves to `flex-basis: content`. The content is the text "*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.*"

So now we know why the flex item doesn't expand and what its width is based on.

**Fixing This Layout**:

This flex layout should not be column-based; it should be row-based. Columns are inside the sole flex item, but not flex items themselves and dimensional flexibility is desired on the x-axis, not the y-axis.

So, `flex-direction: column` needs to become `flex-direction: row`.

The flex layout needs to grow (on the x-axis) to fit available space, so `flex-grow: 1` needs to be specified on the flex item (`.box`).

Lastly, the `grid-template-columns` value should use `auto-fit`, not  `auto-fill` if horizontal centering is desired. Grid items can be centered with `justify-content: center` applied to the grid container element.

(With `auto-fill`, invisible placeholder grid items will be placed to fill out the layout, which will cause the three present grid items to be aligned to the left with a bunch of invisible placeholder items filling out the remaining blank space to their right. With `auto-fit`, those placeholder grid items are simply discarded and that space is freed for horizontal alignment.)

```css
.hero {
  background-color: pink;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 600px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.box {
  border: 1px dotted #000;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-unit {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.hero-modules {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  justify-content: center;
}

.hero-modules .hero-item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-modules .hero-item h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
  <div class="box">
    <div>
      <h1 class="hero-heading">Check out these new features</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="hero-modules">
      <div class="hero-item">
        <div>
          <h3>Title of Item</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a class="hero-read-more">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="hero-item">
        <div>
          <h3>Title of Item</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a class="hero-read-more">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="hero-item">
        <div>
          <h3>Title of Item</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a class="hero-read-more">Read more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button-unit">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary mb-3">Got It</button>
      <p>
        <a class="remind-me-later" href="">Remind me later</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum molestias earum beatae, minima provident sunt a et? Voluptatibus sequi ipsum ad asperiores soluta odio, nam nobis quas non totam ut officiis itaque eveniet, maiores saepe id cum consequuntur.
      Molestias suscipit quia laudantium laborum nemo ab officia, nihil esse mollitia sunt!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your suggested fix of layout doesn't meet requirements in question. OP want grid items to align in one row or one column depending on available size. Here is screenshot of issue http://prntscr.com/j470a2 I'm using Chrome 65, Windows 10

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Did you use the "Full page" view or only the small preview box as shown in the screenshot? (The "Full page" button doesn't become visible until you click "Run code snippet".) The demo code works fine for me in Chromium 65 on Linux Mint 18. It may also be worth noting that both the OP's first and second examples allow for the possibility of the layout shown in your screenshot given a viewport width in which only two columns can fit.

Comment: Even though I don't fully agree with your answer, I apreciate the amount of work that it shows. Also, the snippet seems to be working ok to me

Answer (score 1):

```
Add **display:flex** property to your main container.

 .Main {
     display:flex;
  }
 div {
   flex: 1;
 }
```

Then All div will be act as grid for more information refer below link.
   https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `display: flex` property. Below is the code for it.

```css
.hero-modules {
  display: flex;
}

.hero-modules .hero-item {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-modules .hero-item h3 {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-modules">
  <div class="hero-item">
    <div>
      <h3>Title of Item</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="hero-read-more">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hero-item">
    <div>
      <h3>Title of Item</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="hero-read-more">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="hero-item">
    <div>
      <h3>Title of Item</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta est ipsa recusandae.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a class="hero-read-more">Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I know I can change `display:grid` to `display:flex`.  But I wanted to use a grid instead, and the purpose of this question was to find out _why_ the grid would not work.